# React not able to render an array(state) in a single row

Tags: reactjs, jsx

**The state**

```
state = {
    posts: [],
}
```

The posts gets an API value of

```
{
  "authors": [
    {
      "authorName": "Sideney Sheldon",
      "authorImageURL": "http..."
    },
    {
      "authorName": "Sideney Sheldon",
      "authorImageURL": "http..."
    },
    ....
  ]
}
```

code

```
render(){
  const postList = posts.length ? (
    posts.map(post => {
      return (
        <div className="" key={this.state.key}>
          <div className="containerimager">
            <img  style={imgb} src={post.authorImageURL} />
          </div>
          <h6 style={{ marginTop:"23px"}} >{post.authorName}</h6>
        </div>
      )
    })
  ) : 
  (
      <div className="center">No posts to show</div>
  );

  return(
    {postList}
  )
}
```

The {postlist} returns objects but it returns each object in a new row in the webpage
I want all the results(images) in the same row 
can anyone please help?

Comment: What do you mean by `in a new row`? If you're talking about the design, you should change that using CSS and not React nor JS (unless you're using JSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple elements in the same row, you could achieve that with css. Use `display: flex`(by default flex-direction is `row` which is what you need) on the wrapper to `postList`. You can either pass it as a style though JSX or add a class that specifies this property

```
render(){
  const postList = posts.length ? (
    posts.map(post => {
      return (
        <div className="" key={this.state.key}>
          <div className="containerimager">
            <img  style={imgb} src={post.authorImageURL} />
          </div>
          <h6 style={{ marginTop:"23px"}} >{post.authorName}</h6>
        </div>
      )
    })
  ) : (
  <div className="center">No posts to show</div>
  );

  return(
    <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>{postList}</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [CodeSandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/kw7kl21oj3) I created using your code.

If you're trying to line up the users horizontally (from left to right), CSS is the way to go. In particular, the `<div>` that is being mapped has, by default, the `display: block` style which makes it occupy its own row in the page.

To line up `div`s side by side, you need to somehow apply the `display: inline-block` style. In my example I used a `style` prop, but you will likely want to do it in CSS directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS problem, you should use `display: flex` together with `flex-direction: row` on the parent div which will provide the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

```
posts.map(post,index => {
          return (
            <div className="" key={this.state.key}>
            <div className="containerimager">
  <img  style={imgb} src={post.authors[index].authorImageURL} />
   </div>
<h6 style={{ marginTop:"23px"}} >{post.authors[index].authorName}</h6>
</div>
          )
        })
      ) : (
        <div className="center">No posts to show</div>
      );
```

Try this

Comment: This answer is kind of useless - add explanation and the steps how you came up with this solution ...

Comment: Also this wouldn't even compile ... `posts.map` arguments should be surrounded by brackets: `posts.map((post, index) => { ... })`.

Comment: You are mapping object instead of array. posts.authors will be map